# How can a store tag's into a list C# asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, tags, hyperlink

I want to store a **list of tags** so that i could later on use it in a tag cloud.

The list can be hard coded and does not need to be populated as the application is running,
the list can be edited when ever i would like to add more tags.

**A tag is a link correct?** how would i save the link as a word?

Could someone please show me how i can do this.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: How would i save a ling as a tag, for example your link right here, if i right clicked it copy as link, now how can i save it as a tag where the whole link is hidden behind the word (tried?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> a = new Dictionary<string, string>();
a.Add("tag", "url");
```

Isn't this what you want?

Comment: That could be what i want, how would i then access that again?

Comment: For instance: string outputurl; a.TryGetValue("tag", out outputurl);
But you can do a lot of other things with Dictionaries

Comment: a.ContainsKey("tag"), a.ContainsValue("url"), a.Count, you can loop through all keys or you can even sort them.

Comment: I will have to read up a bit on Dictionaries, But thanks a lot looks very helpful +1